# Why does `subprocess.check_call(..., stderr=sys.stdout)` fail in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.6

```
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Mar  7 2016, 11:15:18) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_call(['echo', 'hi'], stderr=sys.stdout)
echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 488, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['echo', 'hi']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This command, `subprocess.check_call(['echo', 'hi'], stderr=sys.stdout)`, works just fine in Python 2.7 and Python 3. What is Python 2.6 doing differently?

Comment: Could it be a path or permission thing? Does `subprocess.check_call(['/bin/echo', 'hi'], stderr=sys.stdout)` work?

Comment: hm, definitely to do with the redirection of `stderr`, although I can't quickly see what's changed between 2.6 and 2.7 in subprocess.py.

Comment: @jDo that gives the same result. I think if it were a permissions issue, it would be the same across 2.6 and 2.7?

Comment: The documentation suggests using `Popen` directly if you want to redirect the output, so perhaps that's a workaround, although it would still be interesting to find out why this happens.

Comment: @SimonFraser `subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hi'], stderr=sys.stdout).wait()` shows the same `echo: write error: Bad file descriptor` and returns 1.

Comment: The subprocess module has its own references to stdout and stderr. How about: `subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hi'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`?

Comment: @SimonFraser good call! Looks like `STDOUT` works in this case. I'm still curious what the underlying problem is, though. Because there's no equivalent `STDERR` feature, this variant of the problem doesn't have a workaround: `subprocess.check_call("echo foo >&2", shell=True, stdout=sys.stderr)`

Comment: @JackO'Connor I think you're right. That would be logical.

Comment: Try `subprocess.check_call("echo foo >&2", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDERR)`

Comment: Golly, even with `stderr=1` this error occurs. Python 2.7 saw a *lot* of `subprocess` module work, it'll be hard to dig out the exact change that fixed this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug is discussed [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue9074):

```
Transcript to reproduce in Python 2.6.5:

>>> import subprocess, sys
>>> subprocess.call(('echo', 'foo'), stderr=sys.stdout)
echo: write: Bad file descriptor
1
>>> 

Expected behavior:

>>> import subprocess, sys
>>> subprocess.call(('echo', 'foo'), stderr=sys.stdout)
foo
0
>>>
```

> This happens because we've asked the child's stderr to be redirected, but not its stdout. So in _execute_child, errwrite is 1 while c2pwrite is None. So fd 1 (errwrite) correctly gets duped to 2. But then, since errwrite is not None and it's not in (p2cread, c2pwrite, 2), the child closes fd 1.
>
> The equivalent thing happens if you supply stdout=sys.stderr and the child attempts to write to its stderr.
>
> I've attached a patch to fix this. It simply adds 2 and 2 to the list of fds not to close for c2pwrite and errwrite, respectively.
>
> This patch is against the 2.6.5 release.
>
> There is also a workaround, in case anyone else is affected by this bug before a fix has been released:

```
>>> import os, subprocess, sys
>>> subprocess.call(('echo', 'foo'), stderr=os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno()))
foo
0
>>>
```

It was fixed in 2.7 with this [patch](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/a476eb087ee9/) on a related [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue10806).